# Openbravo ERP application using selenium webdriver but not able to find any web element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When I'm trying to run this code, I am unable to find any web element

```
package PremisesManagement;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class openbravo {
    @Test
    public void openbravoLoginTest() throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver d = new ChromeDriver();
        d.get("http://119.81.222.91:8080/camps/security/Login_FS.html");

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        d.findElement(By.id("user")).sendKeys("xyz");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d, 120); 
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("//button[@id='buttonOK']")));
        d.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='buttonOK']")).click();                
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Avnish Rathore - can you be more precise about what the problem is? For example, it's not obvious whether the problem is in `findElement(By.id("user"))` or `findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='buttonOK']"))` or somewhere else.

Comment: HI @VinceBowdren i got the solution ,actually the problem is that ,i am trying to find the elements without Switch the frame., because there are two frame in that UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually located elements are inside a `frame` with id `paramFrame1`, So you need to switch this `frame` before finding element as below :-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://119.81.222.91:8080/camps/security/Login_FS.html");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

//First switch to frame with id paramFrame1  
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("paramFrame1"));

//Now find the element
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("user"))).sendKeys("xyz");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("buttonOK"))).click();
```

Comment: Can u tell me , how i can find frame id?

Comment: @AvnishRathore Just goto browser console by pressing f12 and execute this `document.getElementById("paramFrame1")` and see the result..:)

Comment: @AvnishRathore And to getting all frames execute this into browser console `document.getElementsByTagName("frame")`